# Ensure that assigning RowSource will not fail

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 ComboBoxes which I populate using `RowSource`.
Combobox2 `RowSource` change based on the value of Combobox1.

I have this code:

```
If Combobox1.Value = "Item1" Then Combobox2.RowSource = "Sheet1!Item1"
```

`Sheet1` is the name of the sheet, `Item1` is a named range.

**Problem:**
This works fine if the only workbook open is the one containing this code.
However, if another workbook is open, it fails to reference the `RowSource` correctly.
How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve this, include the `Filename` of the workbook that contains the *RowSource* like this:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "Item1" Then ComboBox2.RowSource = "'[Test.xlsm]Sheet1'!Item1"
```

Or better yet improve it by declaring variables:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Thisworkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

If ComboBox1.Value = "Item1" Then _
   ComboBox2.RowSource = "'[" & wb.Name & "]" & ws.name & "'!" & "Item1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combobox's List property instead, something like:

```
If Combobox1.Value = "Item1" Then 
    Me.ComboBox2.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Workbooks("test").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Item1"))
End If
```

Application.Transpose is needed to turn the range into a one-dimensional array.

Comment: The odd thing is that I see you answering a very similar question, with a very similar answer, last month: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19107555/293078

Comment: actually, that is about adding `Combobox List` from a `Range` which are column headers (horizontal). But what I learned from your post is that i need to add the `Workbook Name` in the `RowSource` reference. I'll try, and i'll get back to you. :)

Comment: yes, adding the workbook name like this `Combobox2.RowSource = "'[Test.xlsm]Sheet1'!Item1"` works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Old post I know but I came across it when trying to figure out the RowSource function (somewhat peculiar calling it RowSource when it takes data from a column).

Anywho, I've been playing around with it a bit & believe the below simplifies it, saves you having to remember when all the quotes, exclamation marks & brackets go.

```
If Combobox1.Value = "Item1" Then Combobox2.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Names("Item1").RefersTo
```

Or if you're not using a named range:

```
If Combobox1.Value = "Item1" Then Combobox2.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Address
```

Comment: That is correct but rather than using `RefersTo`, I'd use this: `ThisWorkbook.Names("Item1").RefersToRange.Address(, , , True)` which will give you the fully qualified Range address with workbook and sheet names. Same goes if you use a normal Range.