# Runtime error '380' : could not set the Rowsource property. Invalid property value

Tags: excel, vba

Is this the correct way to use the rowsource function?

I keep getting `error '380' : could not set the Rowsource property. Invalid property value.` while trying to insert data using my userform.

```
Dim iRow As Long

iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] 

With frmForm

    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 37
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True

If iRow > 1 Then    
     .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:AK" & iRow
     Else
     .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:AK2"
 End If

End With
```

Comment: How do you get `iRow`?

Comment: Yo probably do not have a sheet with the name `Database`.

Comment: Share some more of the code. The `.lstDatabase` part indicates that you are inside a With block.

Comment: @Simon code updated.

Comment: @Storax already assign a sheet name as Database

Comment: I've tested your code by making a userform and putting a listbox on it. Works fine for me so I'm not sure what your problem is besides your sheet name being incorrect as Storax said. If you definitely have everything named correct would you be able to share your file to test with since the problem can't be reproduced? If so upload it to a file host and share the link.

Comment: @simon and all. Thank for your help. i found solution at this page ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062322/ensure-that-assigning-rowsource-will-not-fail ) seem like opening two workbook that contain similar data on the same time will causing rowsource reference issue and getting error "380".